# Regular expression for mobilenumber and phonenumber

Tags: regex, phone-number

Giving the data:
050359554 and 0478770213

I'm searching for a regular expression that will check if the number begins with 04.
If it starts with 04, then it should be followed by a 6,7,8 or 9 and 7 digits.
Otherwise if it starts with only a 0 and no 4 it should be followed by 8 digits.

My current regex is like

```
/^(04[6789]\d{7})$|^(0\d{8})$/
```

The problem with this one is when I enter the number 0478770213 it already says that it's ok at the input of 047877021. But that is not the case.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^0(?:4[6789]\d{7}|(?!4)\d{8})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR7cR7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have a switch group in the regex you provided, the first one is a 10 digits phone number, the second one is a 9 digits.

In your expectations you said :

> Otherwise if it starts with only a 0 and no 4 it should be followed by 8 digits.

But in your regex you did not translate the *"and no 4"*

Your regex should be :

```
/^(04[6789]\d{7})$|^(0[0-35-9]\d{7})$/
```

But something disturbs me, are 9 digits **and** 10 digits phone number legit?
I swear it is a mistake, so i suggest you this :

```
/^(04[6789]\d{7})$|^(0[0-35-9]\d{8})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
/^(04[6789]\d{7})$|^(0(?!4)\d{8})$/
```

This will match `0` not followed by 4, followed by 8 digits.

The interesting with a lookahead is that it will not move the search cursor:

```
0123456789
^ Cursor is here
 ^ Lookahead on this character
^ Cursor is still here
```